# Cross Compiling Rust Crate on Windows for Android

Tags: android, windows, rust, cross-platform

I'm trying to cross compile a practically empty library crate on Windows for Android.
Sadly when doing so, I either get the error that the linker `cc` could not be found or when I try to use `rust-lld` to solve this issue, I get the linker complaining about missing libraries like `-ldl`, `-lunwind` or `-llog`.

As such I probably am missing something fundamental. My google Fu came up empty on how to solve this issue for Windows (without using WSL or Docker, which is basicly saying use Linux instead...). Can someone point me in the right direction or to an up-to-date tutorial for cross compiliation?

Any help is much appreciated.

**Edit:**

The concrete error I'm getting when compiling `example_crate` using the command `cargo build --target x86_64-linux-android` with a `.cargo/config.toml` changing the linker to `rust-lld`:

```
  = note: rust-lld: error: unable to find library -ldl
          rust-lld: error: unable to find library -llog
          rust-lld: error: unable to find library -lunwind
          rust-lld: error: unable to find library -ldl
          rust-lld: error: unable to find library -lm
          rust-lld: error: unable to find library -lc


error: could not compile `example_crate` due to previous error
```

I've created the `example_crate` using `cargo init example_crate` changed the `main.rs` to `lib.rs`and added `crate-type = ["cdylib"]` to the lib section in my `Cargo.toml`.

Comment: Just confirming if you looked at the existing issues like: [Windows CI is borked #88796](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/88796) or other possibly [related issues](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+windows+arm64+)

Comment: Thanks for the links. Sadly they don't contain what appears to be my issue. My problem isn't an undefined symbol, but finding the required libraries to link in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some time i got back to this and found the very helpful `cargo ndk` command which solved the issue for me. It appears like there were issues with finding the Android NDK, and setting ANDROID_NDK_HOME fixed it.